# Rewrite the object from array

Tags: javascript

I have a list of items. Each item has 2 input, one user can change number and second is a checkbox. This are the functions for each input:

```js
 //this is the user array
  const user = [{
      id: '',
      votes: 0,
      active: false
    }
  ];
 
 //this is the function for changing checked status
const checked = (checked, id) => {
    user[id] = {
      id: id,
      votes: how to add here the `votes` state,
      active: checked
    }
  }
  
//this is the function for changing number
const number = (votes, id) => {
    user[id] = {
      id: id,
      votes: votes,
      active: how to add here the `active` state ?,
    }
  }
```

Issues: When I change the number I add votes and also I add id, but I don't have `active` value from the users, the same issue is with `checked` where I need to add `votes`.
 How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Just change the value of the selected key like `user[id].active=...` directly.

```js
//this is the user array
  const user = [{
      id: '',
      votes: 0,
      active: false
    }
  ];
 
 //this is the function for changing checked status
const checked = (checked, id) => {
  user[id].active = checked;
}
  
//this is the function for changing number
const number = (votes, id) => {
  user[id].votes = votes;
}
```

Comment: could help, how to get all objects from user array which have `active: true`, so the rest objects which have `active:false` to not show.

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.filter` function. To get all `active: true`, just do `user.filter(({ active }) => active);`